# GIMP - Stroking with blur effect

Tags: gimp

I need to apply stroking to a selection, when I use "Edit - Stroke selection" standard option - there are empty spaces between selection and stroking. If I increase the stroking line - it gets inside the selection, it looks ugly even with blur effect. Please help me with the task!

I need this image:

[image]

To look like these examples:

[image][image]

Comment: Yes, sure! You are right. Here's the link: http://ge.tt/6Y7vxUi2      The source file lavr.png must look like ardina_yellow.png (this is another logo just as example), ardina.png is the source file of ardina_yellow.png

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stroking the selection directly, try this:

- `Select>To path`
- Remove the selection (save it first if needed: `Select>Save to channel`)
- `Edit>Stroke path`

Your image with:

- color selection
- Select>To path
- Select>None
- Edit>Stroke path (line mode, 2px)

[image]

Comment: I tried as you explained, this is how it looks after stroking: http://ge.tt/3qSeyUi2 (without the selection)

Comment: Your image is way to small to be worked on. The large characters are 5 pixels thick, you outline can be at best two pixels (stroke in "Line" mode). Bu my recommendation is to work only with vectors. Load the image in Inkscape, scale it up and use it as a guide to reconstruct the vector. Then you can get a clean image of any size.

Comment: Oh, thanks! The lines are straight now, the whole image looks better, but small letters are crooked ("v" and "r"). I think I need to edit them manually using brush. And I don't know how to fill those spaces as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

After manual editing and with blur effect

Answer (score 0):

It looks better now, but small letters are not straight, I don't know how to make them look more direct (without curves)